# How to use custom equality via lambda to find a tuple with one matching element in a std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std

Say I have a std::list that looks like this:

```
std::list< std::tuple< UINT, SIZE_T, UINT > > FooList;
```

It's not sorted in any way, and given a UINT, I'd like to search through the list and find whether there's a tuple that matches the UINT using its last element (i.e. <*, *, UINT To Match>). So for example, if I have did this:

```
FooList.emplace_back(100, 0x1000, 200); 
FooList.emplace_back(200, 0x2000, 400);
FooList.emplace_back(400, 0x4000, 800);
```

If I look for 400, I should find the one with 0x2000, but if I look for 100, I should find nothing.

I am looking for a solution using lambdas. Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UINT key = 400;
auto p = std::find_if(FooList.begin(), FooList.end(),
    [key](const std::tuple<UINT, SIZE_T, UINT>& t) {
        return std::get<2>(t) == key;
    });
if (p != FooList.end()) {
    // found p
} // else not found
```

Comment: Nosid, thanks for the quick response. But what if 400 is a variable? How would I pass that in to the lambda?

Comment: Thanks. I see, so we can pass variables to lambda this way. Cool.